# Using Stash variable as Member Categories parameter

Tags: stash, member-categories

I'm trying to retrieve a category ID to be used in the Member Categories tag pair that is used later on in my template.  I know for sure that the variables is being set (I tested it outside the Member Categories tag), but for some reason it refuses to work as a parameter.  I've tried adding process="end" but that didn't seem to do anything.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" limit="1" dynamic="yes" disable="pagination"}
        ...
        {exp:stash:set name="my_id"}
            {categories limit="1"}
                {category_id}
            {/categories}
        {/exp:stash:set}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

...

```
    {exp:member_categories:members category_id="{exp:stash:get name='my_id' process='end'}" limit="4" backspace="1"}
        {screen_name}, 
    {/exp:member_categories:members}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a few different ways to get around the parse order issue. One would be instead of adding process=end you could wrap the member_categories tag pair with stash parse:

```
{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
    {exp:member_categories:members category_id="{exp:stash:get name='my_id'}" limit="4" backspace="1" parse="inward"}
        {screen_name}, 
    {/exp:member_categories:members} 
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

(also added parse=inward to the members tag parameter, but not sure if you'll need it)

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much! FYI for anyone else - did not end up not needing to add parse=inward to get it to work.